# Add tab to Product Information in admin panel

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, adminhtml

I am trying to add a custom tab to the Product Information page:

[image: Custom Tab in Product Information page]

I have followed the instructions on the following websites but have been unable to get the custom tab to appear:

- http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/02/create-custom-tab-in-magento-product-addedit-page.html
- http://magento.roars.in/add-custom-tabs-to-the-magento-product-admin/add-custom-tabs-to-the-magento-product-admin/ *(Site can not be reached)*
- http://www.atwix.com/magento/new-tab-product-edit-page/

How do I add a custom tab to the product information page in the admin panel?

I have the FishPig Wordpress Integration plugin that is adding blog tabs to the page - could these be conflicting with my tab somehow?

[edit]

I have set the FishPig plugin as inactive via its xml file, and my custom tab still does not show - so I do not think there is a conflict with this plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Front-end product tabs:

Please check first if your theme has a tab solution if they do not you can remove the extension you are using now through magento connect and install easytabs extension. It always worked for me.

For Back-end product tabs:
this link gives you step by step how to add product tabs in the backend:
http://phpcmsframework.blogspot.in/2012/12/magento-steps-to-add-custom-tabs-to.html

Comment: easytabs looks like a front-end tab solution for the product page. I am looking to add a tab in the admin panel.

Comment: true, sorry what exactly do you want in the admin tab? I was able to create admim product tabs through creating custom attributes and organizing it in "Manage attributes sets".

Comment: I have been able to create my own attribute group tab as well, but I do not want to create an attribute group. I am creating my own module that creates a tab which shows my own code.

Comment: this is a step by step process for exactly what you need thats all I can think of: http://phpcmsframework.blogspot.in/2012/12/magento-steps-to-add-custom-tabs-to.html

Comment: Brilliant - that's worked :) If you create that as an answer I shall accept it :)

Comment: I have follow this step and add custom tabs successfully  on localhost but i have uploaded the code on server it is not working giving error'wrong configuration tab'

Comment: Link is dead :(