# Extension with many to many relationship with products

Tags: ce-1.5.1.0, entities

I'm new in magento.
i need to create an extension which allows to:

1. Create an entity composed of title, description and image.
2. in the product admin, create a new tab which allows to link the product
   to one or many new created entities.
3. the joining table should
   contain two orders column.

Is there a similar Magento extension from which i can start to create mine?
Thank you

Comment: i forgot to mention that i'm working on the version 1.5.1

Comment: @Shathish. Thanks for the free publicity, but that doesn't work on 1.5. Only 1.7+.

Comment: Read this. Maybe it gives you an idea: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8314/146 I don't know if that works on 1.5 but it should take you in the right direction.