# Add custom tab to configurable product on add/edit product tab Admin side

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I have searched for the issue but didn't find any clue.I studied this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5597/add-tab-to-product-information-in-admin-panel) and so many other's like this for custom tab and i did it.But the issue is that  i want to restrict the tab to be only visible to configurable product and also want to show on  product add tab.Currently it's working for edit.MY admin side xml code is :

```
 <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>my_custom_tab</name>
            <block>mymodule/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this using an observer.  Declare this in the `config.xml` of your module:

```
<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    <observers>
        <[module]>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>[module]/adminhtml_observer</class>
            <method>addProductTab</method>
        </[module]>
    </observers>
</core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
```

Now create the observer `[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Adminhtml/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Adminhtml_Observer {
    public function addProductTab($observer){
                $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
                $product = Mage::registry('product');
                if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs && $this->_canAddTab($product)){
                        $block->addTab('my_custom_tab', array(
                                'label' => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Tab label here'),
                                'content'   => Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('[module]/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab'),
                        ));
                }
                return $this;
        }
        protected function _canAddTab($product){
                if ($product->getId() && $product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
                        return true;
                }
                $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
                if ($request->getParam('type') == 'configurable'){
                        if ($request->getParam('attribtues')){
                                return true;
                        }
                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.I got this error `Fatal error: Class 'My_Module_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/mage16/app/Mage.php` on line 516

Comment: Then create the helper file. Or replace `Mage::helper('[module]')` with `Mage::helper('catalog')`

Comment: This helper exist and also i try with `Mage::helper('catalog')` but didn't work.

Comment: Error removed but still on edit page works , not for add product page ? what should i do now

Comment: it doesn't show for add page after selecting the configurable type or before?

Comment: Yes it only works for edit product page.

Comment: Try to fiddle with the `_canAddTab` method.